# Select the last entry by date and type in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

I have data which I desperately need to analyze and I'm at a loss as to how to proceed. The data is in three columns; the first is date. The dates are not in order (for various reasons) and new data is just added to the bottom of the list. I also have the selling price of a product in the second column and the type of product in the third.  For example:

[image: example of data]

Calculations must be based on the seven most recent prices of any one type. The 3rd lowest price and 2nd highest price go into the table starting with Cells “A” (`F12`) and “B” (`G12`), respectively.

The third formula should eliminate (ignore) the highest and lowest of the seven most recent prices, and calculate the average of the remaining five prices. This goes in the last column of the table, starting with Cell “C” (`H12`).

Then I need a combined bar/line graph
with "type" on the horizontal axis and "price" on the vertical. 
I need a stacked bar graph showing the lower range (Cell “A”) and higher range (Cell “B”), and a line graph is to be overlaid with the averages (Cell “C”).

I'm not an Excel wizard, and I've tried every self-help tutorial I can to work this out. I’ve gotten as far as thinking that `VLOOKUP` may be useful, but I'm now at a loss.

Comment: Thanks for the corrective assistance Bandersnatch and Scott

Comment: Yeah, thanks, @Scott. :-)  Lee, this problem is pretty difficult, for several reasons.  One issue is that the 7 most recent dates for a given type can have more than 7 sales.  I'll take another crack at this tomorrow.

Comment: It sounds complex enough that I think you'd have to use a vba function

Comment: (1) It seems to me that the fact that you have multiple entries per day *per type* (e.g., rows 8 and 10 are both 1-Jun-17, type 7) makes this absolutely unsolvable (even by hand!), because the concept of ‘‘the seven most recent’’ entries of any one type is undefined.  (2) It’s up to you, but, assuming you resolve issue #1, do you believe a line graph really makes sense where one axis (the horizontal, or X, axis) is a type?

Comment: @Scott, yes I did and I thank you. I was interrupted before I finished, but that's no excuse, and I promise to take more care in the future.

Comment: @scott, Thanks for your reply. with regards to multiple entries on the same day effecting "the seven most recent" entrys, I can change the data so this eventuality dosent occure. I can easily ensure at the data entry stage that there are no two entries for the same type on the same date.    With regards to the X axis question, the type is actually a quality rating of the same product. This means a Type 6 is a better quality version of the same product as type 2. Therefore the progression of the sales prices through type on the X axis is a visual useful tool. Thanks so far for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the restriction against multiple sales of the same type on a given day that Scott brought up has made doing this possible.  But it’s still pretty involved.  Using VBA might be a lot simpler, and maybe someone here will post a procedure.

I’m going to start by using a “helper” table because it’s useful to see the intermediate data and double check that things are calculated correctly, but I’ll also show formulas that don’t use the helper table.  The helper table is shown below along with the results.

[image]

I have used random prices and dates, but honored the above restriction about multiple sales of a given type per date.  Now let’s build up the formula that goes in F2.

First, we need an array of the seven most recent prices for each type.  Once that’s available, it's easy to calculate the three metrics in the results table from that array.

We start with this expression: `($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-1)`.  This is part of the formula in F2, so `ROW()-1` equals 1, and this expression gives an array of True/False values, with True wherever Type equals 1 and False everywhere else. As it is filled down, `ROW()` increments, so in the next row, it gives the array with True where Type equals 2, etc.

Now we multiply this array by the column of dates: `($A$2:$A$55)*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-1)`.  This gives an array containing the date where Type equals 1, and False everywhere else.

Now we want the most recent 7 of those dates, and we get those using the `LARGE()` function.  Because of the restriction above (there's only one Type 1 sale on each date), this gives the dates of the 7 most recent sales of Type 1:

`LARGE(($A$2:$A$55)*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-1),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})`

The series of numbers in curly brackets tells `LARGE()` to return the 1st through 7th largest values.

Now we use an `IF()` to get the prices corresponding to those dates:
`IF($A$2:$A$55=LARGE(($A$2:$A$55)*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-1),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-1),$B$2:$B$55)`

The first part of the `IF()`’s logical test returns an array where the date in Column A is one of the 7 dates above, and this array is multiplied by the array where type = 1 again, because other types were sold on those 7 dates.  So the `IF()` tests whether the date in Column A equals one of the array of 7 most recent dates **and** whether the particular sale on that date was for Type = 1.  If both of those conditions are true, the `IF()` returns the sales price from Column B, and False otherwise.

Now to list the prices in the helper table from high to low, we use `LARGE()`:
`(LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$55=LARGE(($A$2:$A$55)*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-1),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-1),$B$2:$B$55),COLUMN()-5)`

This formula is in Column F, so `COLUMN()-5` equals 1, and the formula returns the 1st largest value of the array in that column.  As it is filled across, `COLUMN()` increments, so in the next column, it gives the 2nd largest value, etc.

Finally, the formula is wrapped in `IFERROR()` so it will return a blank where there are less than 7 sales of a given type.  The final formula:

`=IFERROR(LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$55=LARGE(($A$2:$A$55)*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-1),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-1),$B$2:$B$55),COLUMN()-5),"")`

is entered in F2.  Because it’s an array formula, it must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  If entered correctly, Excel will surround the formula with curly brackets {} in the formula bar.  Once entered, select F2 and fill the formula down and then across to give the helper table above.

Now it’s easy to fill the results table.  These two formulas

`=SMALL(F2:L2,3) and
 =LARGE(F2:L2,2)`

calculate the 3rd smallest and 2nd largest value in the first row of the helper table.  And this formula

`=AVERAGE(IFERROR(LARGE(F2:L2,{2,3,4,5,6}),""))`

computes the average of the middle 5 values.  It's also an array formula so it must be entered as above.  Filling these formulas down gives the result table.

To fill the results table without using a helper table, use these three array formulas in F,G and H12 and fill down:

`=SMALL(IFERROR(LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$55=LARGE(($A$2:$A$55)*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-11),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-11),$B$2:$B$55),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}),""),3)`

`=LARGE(IFERROR(LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$55=LARGE(($A$2:$A$55)*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-11),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-11),$B$2:$B$55),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}),""),2)`

`=AVERAGE(IFERROR(LARGE(IFERROR(LARGE(IF($A$2:$A$55=LARGE(($A$2:$A$55)*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-11),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7})*($C$2:$C$55=ROW()-11),$B$2:$B$55),{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}),""),{2,3,4,5,6}),""))`

I hope this helps you out, and I'm sure you can produce the graph you want once you have this data.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Wow! didn't realise it was that complex! really appreciate the time and effort you have put in to this to help me out. Ill work on this in the morning and let you know how I go.

Comment: Hi again. Ive had time to go through this now and it works really well. Thanks so much for you very clear answer. There is one question I have though; how do you alter the formulas for an infinite length column? So in the case of the A column, instead of A2:A55, it would be A2:Ax. This way I can put in an indefinate amount of data without having to redefine the column size.

Comment: Try changing the column references to $A:$A or the equivalent for B and C.  Not exactly sure what will happen, but let me know.  Also, if you found this helpful, accept the answer.

Comment: Never mind, I tried that and it didn't work.  Let me look at this again tomorrow.

Comment: Because of the header row,  the ranges all have to start in row 2.  But you can make them all arbitrarily large, like `$A2:$A5000`, etc.

Comment: Last one, promise. Say I wanted the average to NOT return blank if there are less than 7 sales but still give an average of what data there was, would I just remove the IFERROR() ? Like wise for the small and large, if i still wanted them to return a figure of say the lowest and highest figure of the 6 or fewer data entry per type, do i again remove the IFERROR()?

Comment: No.  It IS returning an average of whatever data is there, except the largest one.  The IFERROR() allows it to work because if it wasn't there, you'd get an #N/A instead of the blank, and that would screw up all three calculations.  I think it's working the way you want it to.  Unless you're saying you want to include the largest price in the average if one is blank.  If that's the case, you'd need to use an IF(COUNT($F2:$L2)<7,(formula with {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} at the end), (original formula)). Also, if you found this whole exercise helpful, please accept the answer.

Comment: sorry, new to this and didn't realise I had to accept the answer, but now done. Thanks ever so much